# Collapse button not moving

Tags: html, css

Got this resource from a friend ,  fiddled around the codes

i want to move this bar down because it is blocking the text, when i add padding-top you can see the image what happened.

```
    #header .header-btn-collapse-nav {
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Thank you

[bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYQTc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `margin-top: 100px;` instead of padding.

Comment: Worked thanks man a lot. I should be mindful more next time!

Answer (score 0):

`Padding` creates "inner spacing" in between the parent and child elements, whereby `margin` is responsible for "outer spacing".

If you want to move the button downwards, without it taking up more screen space, you'll have to use `margin-top: 100px;` instead